# Vbs Addition Sequence Isn't Working?

Tags: vbscript

I am currently trying to made a calculator with Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, and Division with vbs. It all works except addition. When I do addition it sticks the numbers beside each other. So if I entered 2+2 it would equal 22. Here's the script!

```
Dim A
Dim B
Dim C
A=inputbox("Enter Your First Number")
B=inputbox("Enter Your Second Number")
C=A + B
MsgBox("Your answer is:" & C)
```

If anyone knows how to fix this I'd really appreciate it!

-Flare

Answer (score 1):

**Convert `A` and `B` to integers:**

```
Dim A
Dim B
Dim C
A = inputbox("Enter Your First Number")
B = inputbox("Enter Your Second Number")
C = CInt(A) + CInt(B)
MsgBox("Your answer is: " & C)
```